# POM dependency for AEM 6.2 implementation of Amazon S3 Bucket

Tags: maven, amazon-s3, aem

I am trying to implement Amazon S3 in Adobe Experience Manager 6.2 and using maven 3.3.9.
When i add dependency:

```
<dependency>
                <groupId>org.apache.servicemix.bundles</groupId>
                <artifactId>org.apache.servicemix.bundles.aws-java-sdk</artifactId>
                <version>1.11.18_1</version>
</dependency>
```

It is not building project and throwing maven-scr-plugin error: 
SCR Descriptor parsing had failures.

```
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.felix:maven-scr-plugin:1.20.0:scr (generate-scr-scrdescriptor) on project aviva-investors-bundle: SCR Descriptor parsing had failures (see log) -> [Help 1]
```

If I try to add only JAR

```
<!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.amazonaws/aws-java-sdk -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.amazonaws</groupId>
    <artifactId>aws-java-sdk</artifactId>
    <version>1.11.2</version>
</dependency>
```

Build is successful. But I am not able to resolve my project bundle. Bundle is in Installed state. Imported Packages shows: Cannot resolve dependency:

```
com.amazonaws.services.s3,version=[1.11,2) -- Cannot be resolved
```

Not sure what to add in dependency to make my imports work.

```
import com.amazonaws.services.s3.AmazonS3;
import com.amazonaws.services.s3.AmazonS3Client;
import com.amazonaws.ClientConfiguration;
```

etc.

Any help is much needed.

Comment: Is this bundle available as active in 6.2 instance? The aws one!!

Answer (score 1):

When you include a dependency in your maven build it is not push to the osgi container. It would be used only to compile your site bundle.

Heres two options what do can do.
1. Upload the s3 jar as an osgi bundle
2. Create another maven task to deploy third party dependencies to your osgi container. See http://www.cqblueprints.com/tipsandtricks/build-and-deploy-osgi/deploy-third-party-libs.html